# Facebook Connect login no longer working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, facebook, single-sign-on

Facebook Connect login (using their FBML javascript widget) has been working fine for us on Firefox, Safari, Chrome and IE on both windows and mac.  But IE has stopped working :(.  I get this error message now on the popup box that comes up when you click the facebook login button:

```
API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: redirect_uri URL is not properly formatted
```

What happened and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your flash player as suggested on the Facebook Developers page [here](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=293167)

Comment: I have a relatively new system which should have a relatively new flash.  But I installed the latest flash anyway to no avail :(.  Though, of course, that would alienate the majority of my users if bleading edge flash was really the issue.

Comment: too bad; seemed a little kludge. What are you using for debugging?

Comment: for debugging what?  The error is foreign to me, searching facebook yielded no immediate answers.  Was working fine before and continues to work fine on all other browsers.  I typically use firebug for debugging web/javascript issues.